# How to decode internal transaction in mempool

Tags: go-ethereum, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, defi, txpool

i'm researching on how mev works. I know that they are watching all pending transactions, then define function that is swap on dex and calculate amount to do sandwitch. However, when user do a swap, they can use several contracts to do them which lead to different data field on transaction. how to decode them ? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One can utilize tools like Etherscan or other blockchain explorers to interpret the different data fields in transactions used by various contracts for swaps.

These tools enable the examination of the input data of a transaction, leading to a better understanding of the specific function calls and parameters used in the swap.

Analyzing the input data allows for the decoding and interpretation of the various contract interactions, providing clarity on the specific actions taken during the swap.

Additionally, referring to the documentation or source code of the involved contracts can provide further insights into their functionality.